# Re-write java anonymous class in groovy style closure?

Tags: groovy

I am a Java programmer trying to learn groovy. Closures are a bit confusing for me at the moment.

Could I have some help to understand how I can use a closure to replace the abstract code I have below. I'm thinking a function defined as a variable or something like that however I can't crack it yet.

```
//MY ABSTRACT CLASS
public abstract class AbstractResource {

    protected StreamingOutput activityStreamingOutput(serviceResponse){
        return new StreamingOutput() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
                    WebApplicationException {
                        def writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                        writer.write(serviceResponse);
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                }
    }
}

// MY CHILD CLASS
class MaintanenceResourceImpl extends AbstractResource{

    public void doSomething(Reader reader) throws Exception {
          // I'D LIKE TO DO SOMETHING GROOVYISH HERE
          def StreamingOutput = activityStreamingOutput(serviceResponse)
    }
```

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do here (w/o knowing other details), but this:

```
abstract class AbstractResource {

    Closure activityStreamingOutput(serviceResponse){
        { OutputStream os ->
            os.withWriter{ it << serviceResponse }
        }
    }
}

class MaintanenceResourceImpl extends AbstractResource {

    void doSomething(Reader reader) throws Exception {
          activityStreamingOutput(serviceResponse).call someOutputStream
    }
```

Comment: thanks. It looks like there is not real benefit of a closure here. What I did instead was just change the abstract method to use OutputStream os -> os.withWriter{ it << serviceResponse }. As I mentioned I'm still trying to get around where closures are useful and I though anonymous classes was a good one. I'll have to look for a different use case i think